# C++ format placeholders equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, c++, string-formatting

What is format placeholder equivalent in c# (*string.Format("{0:??}") where '??' is placeholder which I asked*) for "*%06d*"?

```
printf("%06d",number);
```

Comment: What does this "placeholder" do in C++?  Are you going to make us look it up in both languages?  By the way, you can do the same for yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you.

```
string st = string.Format("{0:000000} and {1:000000}", 123 ,456);
//st => 000123 and 000456
```

Comment: Hope to help more in future :)